# Joining two firestore collections

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to join two firestore collections using the combineLatest function.  I am fairly close, however the actual join is not picking up one of my collections properly, and thus it doesnt compile.  Here is my code:

```
  this.feeds = combineLatest(
    this.firestore.collection<any>(`layout_feed/${this.userId}/entries`, ref => ref.orderBy('postDate', 'desc')).valueChanges()
    .pipe(
      switchMap(layoutFeeds => {
        const place_ids = uniq(layoutFeeds.map(lf => lf.place_id))
        return combineLatest(
          of(layoutFeeds),
          combineLatest(
            place_ids.map(place_id =>
              this.firestore.collection<any>(`user_places/${this.userId}/places`, ref => ref.where('place_id', '==', place_id)).valueChanges().pipe(
                map(user_places => user_places[0])
              )
            )
          )
        )
      }),
      map(([layoutFeeds, user_places]) => {

        return layoutFeeds.map(layoutFeed => {
          return {
            ...layoutFeed,
            place: user_places.find(p => p.place_id === layoutFeed.place_id) //<--error is here
          }
        })
      })
    )
  )
```

The error  is:

> Property 'place_id' does not exist on 'unknown'

Comment: whats the type of `place_ids` and whats the uniq function? is that custom or from a lib?

Comment: place_ids is of type any, which is what p should be as well

Comment: uniq is a built-in function - here are my imports - import { Observable, Subscription, combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
import { uniq, flatten } from 'lodash'
import { map, take, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: After looking your code, can you debug and see what is containing layoutFeeds? I think layoutFeeds doesn't contain any elements or that elements don't have place_id. If layoutFeeds is not undefined or null after debugging, maybe the issue is in the uniq(...) function.